# generateChangeLog do not export databasechangelog table

Tags: liquibase

My database is running with Liquibase for a while. The *databasechangelog* table is filled with ran changesets.

Now, I would like to generate changelog file for my dev database.

Everything is working with the command "*generateChangeLog*" (https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) except for the table "databasechangelog".

For test purpose, a wrote this simple command:

```
java -jar ./liquibase/liquibase.jar --schemas=public --dataOutputDirectory=./test/ --changeLogFile=./public-data.xml --includeObjects=table:databasechangelog --loglevel=debug  generateChangeLog
```

It's supposed to generate changelog file with *databasechangelog* table structure & data as CSV. But it generate only the root XML element:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd"/>
```

Consequence: When I run the generate changlog file on an empty database & run application, Liquibase replay all old changlog and fail as the *databasechangelog* table is empty.

I tried to:

- Explore the Github repository to find a rule that exclude this table => Seems not
- Grant all privileges to my PG user on the database/public schema

Any idea on this?

Comment: `databasechangelog` table keeps a track of successfully ran changesets on DB. We don't need to generate data for this table as a output of `generateChangeLog` command. From consequence mentioned in the question, if you are running changelog on empty database, `databasechangelog` table will automatically populate data (storing all successfully ran changesets)

Comment: We can't replay all changeset from empty databasechangelog table. For exemple: Few month ago, I wrote a changset that create a new table, now, this table is in production and I export It with generateChangeLog.

When I run my application, stratup failed because the table already exist (one exemple over millions)

Comment: In that case, are you looking for `liquibase diff` to generate data which differs in two DBs; Your test env and prod env DB. Whatever output it generates, then can be run on your production DB as the diff data would not exist there.